# What to return from wcf service if requested data is not found

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

My simple wcf returning some data as dto object (MyDataDto). This dto is ofcourse created using MyData object which is created using data returned from repository.

```
public MyDataDto GetData(string filter)
{
   MyData data = repository.GetData(filter);
   return new MyDataDto(data);
}
```

If this data object is null (no data returned from repository) then I'm getting exception (ofcourse).

Question is: Should I decorate my `OperationContract` method with `ObjectNotFoundException` and to handle that exception at client side or to add new property at `MyDataDto` object with property `bool IsEmpty` and to return empty object?

Since I'm pretty new using wcf service what you consider as better practice or you suggest something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can not use a normal .net exception in order to propagate the error to the client you can  use a customized  exception  through  the  use of the [FaultContract Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) something  like  this

```
     [DataContractAttribute]
  public class MyDataDtoFault
  { 
    private string report;

    public MyDataDtoFault(string message)
    {
      this.report = message;
    }

    [DataMemberAttribute]
    public string Message
    {
      get { return this.report; }
      set { this.report = value; }
    }
  }  

    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(MyDataDtoFault))]
    public MyDataDto GetData(string filter)
    {
       MyData data = repository.GetData(filter);
        if (data==null)  
             throw new MyDataDtoFault("No result Was found");  
       return new MyDataDto(data);
    }
```

or you can use a simple [FaultException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.faultexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by default  which is serilizable and represents a SOAP fault.

but creating a property  IsEmpty it will be correct but the client who would like to consume the service must  be aware that this property means no  result was found
personally I prefer raising an exception which is more convenient way of  doing this

Comment: throwing exceptions if there is no data found is bad practice. not only is a perf hit but also makes no sense by flowing your logic based upon some data findings. Sorry - had to downvote here.

Comment: you  are free to comment but give a down  vote it's  not correct I'm explaining the right way to  do exception in wcf that's all did you  have an idea if the MyDataObject could contain's  1000  of ptoperties how can be the service if what you are telling is correct how can you explain that .net throw  FileNotFountException

Comment: understood however this is where my answer comes in play. if you have 1000's of properties then you seriously need to think about redesigning your architecture of your application and data being returned back. But also any exceptions should be caught back and returned in a friendly string manner (logged on the server where the exception happened) so the consumer knows how to display it back or handle it. you also risk exposing errors like if a SQL Database did not exist... then you risk returning that exception detail back if you decided to do that - catching then re throwing is bad

Comment: ok I perfectly understood but AFAIK using FaultException it's SOAP-compliant and any client can consume a Web service without overhead of redefining the architecture

Comment: I'm not speaking about includeExceptionDetailInFaults this will expose  your application to a serious security problem

Answer (score 0):

The best practice and recommended way is to NOT throw exceptions if you have found data and then have your program flow the exceptions. This not only produces performance hits and issues but also is just bad flow of logic. Also means difficult to maintain and lengthy code blocks/spaghetti junction.

The best practice is to create a class which has a Success property for example to indicate if the operation was a success (i.e no SQL Errors or any other exceptions) and then return the data in an exposed property in this custom class. If there is no data then really MyData is null and therefore the client side can check to see if it is null (or if collection... make sure the items are 0 in count/length and instantiated as empty). Example...

```
[DataContract]
public sealed Class MyDataResults
{
   public MyDataResults()
   {
      this.Success = false;
      this.FailureInformation = string.Empty;
      this.Results = new MyData();
   }

   [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
   public bool Success {get; set;}

   [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
   public MyData Results {get; set;}

   [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
   public string FailureInformation {get; set;}
}
```

you return MyDataResults instead.

this also means you have a nice POCO object to deal with and has more meaning of a contract in that "I guarantee the client will receive this object and not something they don't expect and maybe even produce contract breakage"

So if you have an exception on server side (like FileNotFound for example), set the Success to false, set the FailureInformation to a nice friendly message to return back.
The client would check to see if the operation was a Success and if not, display the FailureInformation.

Comment: Your "best practice" can be a worst practice. It takes us back to the days when code had to check the return status of every operation. Such code often forgot to check the status. That's why exceptions were invented - to give a "return status" which cannot be ignored.

Comment: Well actually its so much more common now to do so to check for that status. Trust me, this aint "bad practice" but everyone has their opinions I guess. Whatever floats your boat... but I certainly don't do that. Why throw exceptions based upon if there is no data available? What about other factors? This basically says if a business domain logic is not met then throw exceptions!.

Comment: Just because it's common doesn't make it a best practice. In this case, it's a common worst practice. And, if you read my answer, I don't suggest throwing exceptions based on no data available. Finally, they are not exceptions in this context - they are SOAP Faults. WCF happens to produce a SOAP Fault when a `FaultException<T>` is thrown. A different mechanism could have been chosen which did not use exceptions at all.

Comment: I agree common doesn't make it best practice... I never said that at all. It is a practice used industry wise in different types of organisations especially enterprise. I also never questions the type of exceptions or faults being raised by WCF. I think you are misunderstanding what I am saying, sorry about that. I'm trying to help people develop better, it is what I do, who I am - sorry!

Answer (score 0):

My practice is to return a fault if the operation cannot do what it was requested to do. However, one then needs to examine what it was that the operation was requested to do:

1. `public MyDto GetEntityById(int id)`

   This operation has been requested to return the entity with the given ID. If it cannot do that, then I feel it is appropriate to return a fault.
2. `public List<MyDTO> GetEntitiesMatchingFilter(string filter)`

   This operation is being asked to return a list of entities matching the filter. If there are no entities matching the filter, then this is not a reason to return a fault. It's a normal, expected result.

   On the other hand, if the operation cannot return any entities because of a failure to connect to the database, *that's* a good reason to return a fault.